# how does R choose eigenvectors?

Tags: r, eigenvector

When given a matrix with repeated eigenvalues, but non-defective, how does the R function `eigen` choose a basis for the eigenspace? Eg if I call `eigen` on the identity matrix, it gives me the standard basis. How did it choose that basis over any other orthonormal basis?

Comment: This question may also do well at [stats.se] or [math.se], since it's rather theoretical. (The frequency of questions that use *"orthonormal basis"* correctly is rather low ... until we eventually get `purrr::orthonormal()`, that is :-)

Comment: @r2evans I did puzzle over which site was better, but the accepted answer provided a complete reference, so it worked out.

Comment: Yeah, SO can be a catch-all at times and therefore easy to default to. There are a lot of mathematicians and statisticians around on SO so that often you can get an informed answer, whereas Stats and Math are much-less populated. Glad you got an answer.

Comment: @r2evans, just wondering about `purrr::orthonormal()`, Oh, dumb me, not developed, yet. Okay, I'll rise to the low bar challenge of using 'orthonormal basis' incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not a full answer, but digging a little deeper: the source code of `eigen` shows that for real, symmetric matrices it calls `.Internal(La_rs(x, only.values))`

The `La_rs` function is found [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bc510a79afe61e0ff6ccfa397a0f4b7fbea976df/src/modules/lapack/Lapack.c#L192-L195), and going through the code shows that it calls the LAPACK function `dsyevr`

The `dsyevr` function is documented [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen_gaeed8a131adf56eaa2a9e5b1e0cce5718.html):

> DSYEVR first reduces the matrix A to tridiagonal form T with a call
> to DSYTRD.  Then, whenever possible, DSYEVR calls DSTEMR to compute
> the eigenspectrum using Relatively Robust Representations.  DSTEMR
> computes eigenvalues by the dqds algorithm, while orthogonal
> eigenvectors are computed from various "good" L D L^T representations
> (also known as Relatively Robust Representations).

The comments provide [this link](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node70.html) that gives more expository detail:

> The next task is to compute an eigenvector for $\lambda - s$. For each $\hat{\lambda}$ the algorithm computes, **with care**, an optimal twisted factorization
> ...
> obtained by implementing triangular factorization both from top down and bottom up and joining them at a **well chosen** index r ...

[emphasis added]. The emphasized words suggest that there are some devils in the details; if you want to go further down the rabbit hole, it looks like the internal [dlarrv function](https://web.archive.org/web/20221205081050/https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/d9b/group__double_o_t_h_e_rauxiliary_ga420406ddf3a9d559a40543fa70829ae8.html#ga420406ddf3a9d559a40543fa70829ae8) is where the eigenvectors actually get calculated ...

> For more details, see DSTEMR's documentation and:
>
> - Inderjit S. Dhillon and Beresford N. Parlett: "Multiple representations
>   to compute orthogonal eigenvectors of symmetric tridiagonal matrices,"
>   Linear Algebra and its Applications, 387(1), pp. 1-28, August 2004.
> - Inderjit Dhillon and Beresford Parlett: "Orthogonal Eigenvectors and
>   Relative Gaps," SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, Vol. 25, 2004.  Also LAPACK Working Note 154.
> - Inderjit Dhillon: "A new O(n^2) algorithm for the symmetric
>   tridiagonal eigenvalue/eigenvector problem",
>   Computer Science Division Technical Report No. UCB/CSD-97-971,
>   UC Berkeley, May 1997.

Comment: So does the `eigen()` function in R, lets say for a real symmetric matrix, always output orthonormal eigenvectors? Even when there exists eigenvalues with multiplicity greater than one.

Comment: I don't know; try experimenting?

Comment: Ok, just wondering as this was accepted as an answer, from my experiments they always seem to be.

Comment: I definitely don't know.  There is some discussion re: Julia here. https://discourse.julialang.org/t/are-eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-or-hermitian-matrix-computed-from-eigen-all-orthogonal/60893/11. The test that fails for Julia (i.e. a degenerate case that doesn't give orthonormal vectors) succeeds in R (`v <- eigen(diag(2)+1e-14*matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2))$vector; crossprod(v)-diag(2)`).  But it would take more digging to see if this is *guaranteed*.

Answer (score 0):

It probably uses some algorithm written in FORTRAN a long time ago.

I suspect there is a procedure which is performed on the matrix to adjust it into a form from which eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be easily determined. I also suspect that this procedure won't need to do anything to an identity matrix to get it into the required form and so the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are just read off immediately.

In the general case of degenerate eigenvalues the answers you get will depend on the details of this algorithm. I doubt there is any choice being made - it's just whatever it spits out first.

Comment: I think you're right, but I am wondering about the details of the algorithm, which I imagine is likely standard. The form it puts the matrix into could be a well known special form.

Comment: I think it's described here http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node70.html